# How to achieve two different alignments inside a html option tag?

Tags: css, xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have a select html tag with country calling codes.

```
<select name="countryCallingCode" id="countryCallingCode">
    <option value="1"><span class="name">Afghanistan</span><span class="code">+93</span></option>
    <option value="2"><span class="name">Albania</span><span class="code">+355</span></option>
    <option value="3"><span class="name">Algeria</span><span class="code">+213</span></option>
</select>
```

I want the name to be left aligned and the code to be right aligned. Presentation should look like:

```
Afghanistan                +93   
Albania                   +355   
Algeria                   +213
```

I have introduced the span elements to achieve this with CSS.

```
select#countryCallingCode span.name {text-align: left;}
select#countryCallingCode span.code {text-align: right;}
```

Above code, is not working. Moreover, span elements seem to be not valid inside a html option tag for XHTML 1.0 strict.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

I faced this issue once and what I did was format the text in a monospaced font and fill the middle with spaces to seperate the text and make each row an even number of characters.

Comment: I do this as well.  Most server-side languages provide a printf() type function that can be used to generate the correct number of spaces for each option.

Comment: I wish there were something better, but this is all I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
select {width:100px;}
.name  {float:left;}
.code  {float:right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify the select box with javascript:

find the longest country name, then modify every option so there are enough spaces between country name and calling code.

Answer (score 0):

Mono-spacing is the correct answer but.... you can get pretty close (not perfect) using some jQuery to repeatedly measure a text string in a hidden span.

```
var list = [ ["Afghanistan","+93"], ["Albania","+355"], ["Algeria","+213"] ] ;
var max = 0;
for (n = 0; n < list.length; n++)
{
    var s = list[n][0] + "..." + list[n][1]; 
    $('#dummy').html(s);
    var x = $('#dummy')[0].offsetWidth;
    list[n].push(x);
    if (max < x) max = x;
}

for (n = 0; n < list.length; n++)
{
    var fill = max - list[n][2];
    var s = "...";
    while (true)
    {
        $('#dummy').html(s);
        var x = $('#dummy')[0].offsetWidth;
        if (fill <= x) break;
        s += ".";
    }
    var html = list[n][0] + s + list[n][1];
    $('#countryCallingCode').append($('<option></option').val(n+1).html(html));     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mono-space JS solution to go along with Scott Evernden's JQuery example.  I only tested it in Firefox, but this should be enough to start with.

The JavaScript

```
var MIN_SPACES_BETWEEN_VALS = 3;

function mkOption(left, right, total)
{
    var str = left;
    var spaces = total - left.length - right.length;
    for(x = 0;x < spaces;x++)
        str += "\xA0";

    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.text = str + right;
    opt.value = right;
    return opt;
}

function populate(selId, vals)
{
    var sel = document.getElementById(selId);

    var maxLeft = -1;
    var maxRight = -1;
    for(idx = 0;idx < vals.length;idx++)
    {
        if(vals[idx][0].length > maxLeft)
            maxLeft = vals[idx][0].length;

        if(vals[idx][1].length > maxRight)
            maxRight = vals[idx][1].length;
    }

    var total = maxLeft + maxRight + MIN_SPACES_BETWEEN_VALS;
    for(idx = 0;idx < vals.length;idx++)
        sel.add(mkOption(vals[idx][0], vals[idx][1], total), null);   
}
```

The HTML

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="selectTest.js">

        </script>
        <style>
            select
            {   
               font-family: Courier, mono;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <select name="countryCallingCode" id="countryCallingCode">
        </select>
        <script>
            var vals = [["Afghanistan", "+93"], ["Albania", "+355"], ["Algeria", "+213"]];
            populate("countryCallingCode", vals);
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```