# Select dropdown menu text split left and right?

Tags: html, css, select, styling, html-select

Not sure if this can be done but can I split the text in the option tags?

Example, normal styling:

```
<select>
    <option value="">First - A</option>
    <option value="">Car - B</option>
    <option value="">Black - C</option>
    <option value="">Super Duper - D</option>
</select>
```

How can I get it to look like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="">First       - A</option>
    <option value="">Car         - B</option>
    <option value="">Black       - C</option>
    <option value="">Super Duper - D</option>
</select>
```

I've tried added a span tag nested in the option tag but that didn't work

Comment: I think the answers to this question may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752/how-do-i-put-a-space-character-before-option-text-in-a-html-select-element#25758

Comment: @betafish thanks &nbsp; works as well for this, still not what I'm looking for

Comment: same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484397/how-to-achieve-two-different-alignments-inside-a-html-option-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<option>` tags do not accept HTML content. You can only pad your selections with spaces to format them.

Alternately, there are plug-in replacements for `<select>` that use `DIV`s and `UL`s instead of `<select>` that give you more flexibility.

Comment: but the style attribute is available just not sure if I can style only half/part of the text. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: Yes, you can apply CSS to the element, but not portions of it.

Answer (score 0):

The easier will be to use non proportional (monospaced) font for those boxes and then using right count of nonbreaking spaces like this:

```
<style>
    select{
        font-family:monospace;
    }
</style>
<select>
    <option value="">First&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- A</option>
    <option value="">Car&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- B</option>
    <option value="">Black&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- C</option>
    <option value="">Super Duper&nbsp;- D</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work as expected as each letter will be sized differently thus causing a staggering look

Comment: important thing is to change font type to monospaced one. like courier and similar.
If you copy whole exmaple I sent you into a new .html file and open it in our browser, you should see, it's alligned correctly.
Tried in chrome and IE9