# Split text in drop down to align part on right and another part on left

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am tring to figure out if it is possible to split the text in a dropdown menu and align part to the left and part to the right.

example:

```
options would look like this:

Ebay       03/15/2010
Amazon     08/14/2011 
Uship      07/24/2009
```

here is my coding:

```
<div>
  <p><select name="select1" id="select1" size="22">
    <% @callbacks.each do |callback| %>
      <% if @lead.id == callback.id %>
        <option value="<%= callback.id %>" selected ><%= callback.name %> <%= callback.callback.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %></option>
      <% else %>
        <option value="<%= callback.id %>" onDblClick="doubleClickLead(<%= callback.id %>)"><%= callback.name %> <%= callback.callback.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %></option>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </select></p>  
</div>
```

I would like this part left aligned

```
<%= callback.name %>
```

and this part Right aligned

```
<%= callback.callback.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %>
```

Comment: I don't think that's likely on a standard form control, but a custom control (e.g. the [Bootstrap component](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) might allow you to style the options like that.

Comment: You can find same question and solution here 

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568484/select-dropdown-menu-text-split-left-and-right