# How to set spacing between text inside option from select tag

Tags: html, css

I am displaying  tag with number of options and every option contain two text separated by single space ,so what I want is one text should appear left side and second part should appear right side.

for example :
 text  1234

I want text  in dropdown should come left side and 1234 should come right side of  option in dropdown so by which  css property can acheive this for all `<option></option>`

```
<select id=""  class="form-control ">
  <option> Select options </option>
  <option>text  1234</option>
  <option>text  1234</option>                                                                               
  <option>text  1234</option>                                                                              
  <option>text  1234</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752/how-do-i-put-a-space-character-before-option-text-in-a-html-select-element and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568484/select-dropdown-menu-text-split-left-and-right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put a space character before option text in a HTML select element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752/how-do-i-put-a-space-character-before-option-text-in-a-html-select-element)

Comment: @Virginia I already tried  this solution but it didn't work for me

Comment: Sorry to hear that those solutions did not work. It is a good idea to mention or link to the answers/other sources you used, so that other members don't offer you solutions you already tried ;) For more info, see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Anonymous, if you cna use javascript, you can try this option - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zMgjdj  and styling options as per your requirement , as option styling is mainly limited to font and it doesn't allow child elements

Answer (score 0):

Select option element styling is very limited and custom layout is impossible. You'll need a replacement select control to achieve your goal. Take a look at [selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js), [select2](https://github.com/select2/select2), [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) plugins for a quick solution.